# Mechanical Turks and Watson

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, mechanicalturk, watson

1. Is there any way we can ask the Mturk Worker to open a Watson Knowledge Studio account and do some task of annotating there?
2. In such a case, how to monitor the work progress of the turks either through Watson or through Mturks API?
3. Is there a way we can monitor this task and ensure that the worker does not redo the same task again?

Trying to get some annotation of text done with Watson intelligence and workforce of mturks. Watson has a human annotator module but it seems very contained within its infrastructure.

Any inputs are appreciated.

Comment: Is there an API (in any language) in the Watson Knowledge Studio account? If so, I'd be open to chatting about ways to help you get this done and sharing back with the community.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/services-catalog.html

Comment: Annotating documents in WKS requires subject matter experts who are familiar with the source content. Having general public annotating your documents is likely to end up with nothing useful, even if you have a strict IAA.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Using WEP,WLI, etc.
3. Yes, Connecting options of Watson are available with orchestration tools.